# DBT tests - moving "good" rows to the next table

Tags: testing, cicd, dbt

I have a model called "stg_skills" that I run and then perform **dbt test --model**.

The next model is "dwh_skills".

Let's say the table "stg_skills" has 1,000 rows and 990 of them passed all tests, how do I populate the "dwh_skills" with those 990 good rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform `dbt run` + `dbt test`, you will not prevent downstream models to be populated with data that did not pass tests:  you are just running evertything, and then checking tests on all the ran models.

On the other hand, though, you can also use `dbt build`. With this command, "tests on upstream resources will block downstream resources from running, and a test failure will cause those downstream resources to skip entirely" (see docs [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/build)), meaning that if there's a breaking test in `stg_skills`, `dwh_skills` will not be built until that error is fixed.

In my opinion, that's the closest you can get. I believe there's no way to just run those rows where the tests passed - it is either all or nothing.